# Having trouble understanding a sentence from 1945. Especially 滿鮮二土著セシメテ生活ヲ營ム

Tags: translation

Here's the full sentence from [this Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%99%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E6%8A%91%E7%95%99):

> また同日には「大陸方面二於テハ在留邦人及武裝解除後ノ軍人ハ『ソ』聯 ノ庇護下二滿鮮二土著セシメテ生活ヲ營ム如ク『ソ』聯側二依賴スルヲ可トス」ことを記した「關東軍方面停戰狀況二關スル實狀報告」が作成されソ連側に送付された。

Here's how I understand it:

> Also, on the same day, the “Current State Report Regarding the Armistice Situation in the Kwantung Army Area” was produced and sent to the Soviet side. It stated: “The Japanese expatriates and the disarmed soldiers in the continent area are put under the protection of the Soviet Union, and the native population living in Manchukuo and Korea are to be treated as the Soviet side desires.”

I was fumbling for meaning in that old cited sentence and suspect that the translation is somewhat (or completely) off. Any help in deciphering it is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but we don't do proof reading. Is there a particular part of the sentence that you're having problems with? If so, please focus on that part and explain your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

土著 is a rare word, but in Chinese it seems to mean "native" as in "native American", so I guess this 土著せしむ means "naturalize" (or more literally, "nativize"). Note that せしむ is an (old) causative form (=させる). Assuming this is true, the basic structure of the sentence is:

> 大陸方面二於テハ在留邦人及武裝解除後ノ軍人ハ **(☆)** 如ク『ソ』聯側二依賴スルヲ可トス。
>
> = 大陸方面においては、在留邦人および武装解除後の軍人は **(☆)** よう、ソ連側に依頼してよい。
>
> On the (Asian) continent, the Japanese expatriates and the disarmed soldiers can ask the Soviet Union to **(☆)**.

Where **(☆)** is:

> 『ソ』聯 ノ庇護下二滿鮮二土著セシメテ生活ヲ營ム
>
> = ソ連の庇護下に満鮮に土著させて生活を営む
>
> to naturalize themselves in Manchukuo/Korea and lead lives under the protection of the Soviet Union

So the sentence says the expatriates and the disarmed soldiers can stay in 満鮮 and live there forever *if they desire to do so*.